# CSS extracting image from image strip

Tags: html, css, image

I am examining a website and noticed the following

Consider this navbar

[image]

it gets its background images from an image strip, below

[image]

How do they extract images from an image strip in CSS? or am I wrong in my interpretation that the images are extracted?

Comment: You should look into CSS sprites.

Comment: @Shaggy Im looking at the sprite example on W3Schools but how would you know to how many picks you should set  `background: url(img_navsprites.gif) -91px 0`

Comment: By measuring it in your image editor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

`background-position` to show each image in its postion

```
background-position:-30px 150px;
```